# Handling nullable productions in LR(0) grammars

Tags: parsing, syntax, grammar

I think it's a pretty straightforward question, but I couldn't find the answer anywhere.

If I have a grammar with a non-terminal that derivates NULL, like this:

1. S -> B$
2. B -> idP
3. P -> (E)
4. P ->
5. E -> B

How do I handle the production #3 to diagram the LR(0) states of it? Do I have to include a column corresponding to the transition with the empty set in my LR(0) parsing table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The item `P -> ·` is not different from any other item with the `·` at the right-hand end; the fact that nothing precedes the `·` does not make it special. The closure of the item

```
B -> id · P
```

will be the state `q`:

```
B -> id · P
P -> · ( E )
P -> ·
```

from which `goto(q, P)` will indicate a transition to `B -> id P ·` and goto(q, `(`) will indicate a transition to `P -> ( · E )`. `goto` on `$` and `)` are not defined on that state, but `action` is; it will indicate that `P` should be reduced using the `P ->` rule, after which `goto(q, P)` will be used.